# Installing a .tgz

Tags: linux

I've spent quite a bit looking for the answer to this, and I just want to go to bed. I downloaded a file that turned out to be a .tgz file. So i found instruction on how to unpack it or whatever its called. I now have just a normal folder with a bunch of files, but I have no clue how to install it. Keep in mind I have never used Linux before. I am using linux on a chromebook, so I don't know if that changes anything.

Comment: Arch-based packages are distributed as tarballs and installed using `pacman`.  This could have been built specifically for Arch.  That means they may have something for your distro as well.

Chromebook uses ChromeOS which is Gentoo-based and uses the portage package manager.  I'm not quite as familiar, but see if the software distributor supplies a `*.tbz2` version which could be installed with `emerge -k *.tbz2`.  Even better... do you have the sources so you can package it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should avoid installing software from that type of file (.tgz is just a shortened way of writing .tar.gz). The first place you should look when you want to install something is your package manager. If you're using a Debian based distro, such as Ubuntu or Linux Mint, this would be `apt`.

Package managers take care of putting all the files in the right places, and they make it very easy for you to install things. For example, you might run `sudo apt-get install firefox` to install Firefox. Package managers also take care of updates and cleanup (uninstallation).

However, if you find that the software you want is not available through your package manager, you might have to install it from a tar file. In this case, you should follow the instructions provided by the developers of that software. Be wary though, as installing software this way is not secure. Packages that you install through your package manager are carefully maintained by trustworthy people, whereas this is not always the case when you install something through a tar file.

Essentially, if you install something through your package manager, it's easier, safer, and is likely to work out of the box. It is the way you should install software. If you absolutely must install software from a tar file, make sure you trust the place you're getting it from, and follow their directions.

Comment: @Fox right, I tried to say that with the "cleanup" bit, but I wasn't clear enough.